# Angular JS : ng-grid row color

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid to show the customer data from database, what i want to do is to give a row color which is alltoted to customer.

for example customer 1 has select red color so all the data related to customer 1 should be in a row with red color. is it possbible?

i have been searching and all i got to know is

```
rowTemplate
```

but i dont know if it will fix my dynamic row coloring problem

Comment: Did u try any code? If so update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with ng-class

In your view :

```
<yourrow ng-class="{'oftheuser': user.id == row.userid}"></yourrow>
```

In your css :

```
yourrow.oftheuser{
   background-color:red
}
```

You have to give us some code for a better example :p